# Qual a diferença entre gramática e ortografia?

Tags: gramática, ortografia

Sempre fico em dúvida do que é gramática e o que é ortografia, gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre essas definições.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ortografia e Gramática

Muitos têm dúvidas quanto à nomenclatura *“ortografia”* e *“gramática”*. Afinal de contas, quando você cometeu um erro ortográfico e quando o problema foi gramatical?

Na verdade, a ortografia é uma parte constituinte da gramática.

> “a gramática nada mais é do que o conjunto de normas que dizem
>   respeito à linguagem padrão. Esse conjunto inclui a concordância,
>   acentuação, pontuação e inclusive a ortografia.”

Segundo o **Dicionário Houaiss da Língua Portuguesa**

> Ortografia significa o conjunto de regras estabelecidas pela gramática
>   normativa que ensina a grafia correta das palavras, o uso de sinais
>   gráficos que destacam vogais tônicas, abertas ou fechadas, processos
>   fonológicos como a crase, os sinais de pontuação esclarecedores de
>   funções sintáticas da língua e motivados por tais funções etc.

Ainda segundo o dicionário:

> Gramática significa o conjunto de prescrições e regras que determinam
>   o uso considerado correto da língua escrita e falado. A grande
>   diferença, portanto, é que a ortografia não diz respeito à língua
>   falada, sendo estritamente um conjunto de regras para a linguagem
>   escrita. Afinal, “orto” quer dizer “correto”, e “grafia” quer dizer
>   “escrita”. Ou seja, a escrita correta.

Comment: Muita gente usa o termo "gramática" quando na verdade quer dizer "sintaxe".

Comment: "sintaxe" que também faz parte da "gramática".

Comment: É, eu diria que é um uso metonímico.

Answer (score 4):

Ortografia é a forma correta de se escrever. (Orto=correta Grafia=escrita) 
No caso, quando se escreve errado, há um erro ortográfico.

Por exemplo: erado. (errado)

Já a gramática estuda as normas da Língua Portuguesa. 
A ortografia está incluída dentro do estudo da gramática.